# How to dynamically generate Makefile targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a few files named `foo.c`, `bar.c`, `baz.c`, ... I want to create a Makefile target for each one that runs a build task.

```
foo:
  make foo.c
.PHONY: foo

foo.c:
  run build foo

bar:
  make bar.c
.PHONY: bar

bar.c:
  run build bar

...
```

I essentially just want to do `make foo` and it builds `make foo.c`. But I have x number of files and want to have make tasks for each. How to accomplish this. Something like:

```
FILES = $(foo bar baz ...)

$(FILES): $(FILES)
  make $(FILE)
.PHONY: $(FILE)

$(FILES).c: $(FILES)
  run build $(FILE)
```

But all the files are independent from each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [*pattern rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) for the `.c` targets and [*static pattern rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) for the ones that have to be phony targets (i.e., `foo` and `bar` in your example):

```
targets := foo bar

.PHONY: $(targets)

# static pattern rule
$(targets): %:
   make $*.c

# pattern rule
%.c:
   run build $*
```

Comment: This answer got me further along, but i can't figure out how to make a generic `make build` that runs all the targets.